# How to call overloaded method when the parameter is a subclass of a given type?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, polymorphism, overloading

I have an abstract class `A`, two sub-classes called `B`, `C` and two overloaded methods who are in a separate class:

```
public void process(B objB) {...}
public void process(C objC) {...}
```

From a repository, I retrieve an entity whose type is `A` and I would like to make a call like this:

```
A objA = repo.findById(id);
process(objA);
```

I know a cast is required but I don't want to make a lot of checks using the `instanceof` or plenty of `if` statements.

Which are the best options to implement such a method call?
And is it such a code design good?

Comment: Are the overloaded methods within the classes?

Comment: Nope. They are in a separate class.

Comment: Can you include some of your code?

Comment: @MrsNickalo I think it's irrelevant what's in my code. I just take some data from the repository, I process it and convert it to a DTO that is sent to the controller. What I'm interested in is if such a method overloading is a good architectural decision and if it is, how should I make the call as efficient as possible. If the type of the parameters were different, the call would have been much easier since no cast would have been necessary.

Comment: Such a method overloading is not a good architectural decision. _Effective Java_ covers this practice extensively in the chapter **Use overloading judiciously**.

Comment: It is also interesting to note the problem here stems from using _procedural programming_. `B` and `C` are data classes (structs) while the logic to process them is in a separate class (a service or utility). Applying object-oriented programming is the obvious solution: combine the data and its logic together in one class.

Comment: @jaco0646 Thanks for the clarifications. In the end, I moved the `process` method at the base class level and overridden it into the concrete classes as you suggested below. You can comment as well to this post so I can mark it as an accepted answer. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `instanceof` is not good option especially if you have plenty of places where you need to have access to particular subclass.

1. Obvious approach is to add abstract `process()` method without params into base class and implement it in subclasses by calling corresponding `process(this)` method from another class and passing `this`reference into it.
2. When it is preferred to divide processing logic from class hierarchy (presumably it is your case) there is a pair of patterns: [**Strategy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or more general [**Visitor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).
   Here is an example of **Visitor** pattern usage:

   ```
   abstract class A {
       <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor);
   }

   class B extends A {
       @Override
       public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
           return visitor.visit(this);
       }
   }

   class C extends A {
       @Override
       public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
           return visitor.visit(this);
       }
   }

   interface Visitor<T> {
       T visit(B bObject);
       T visit(C cObject);
   }
   ```

   Then define particular operation by implementing corresponsing visitor:

   ```
   Visitor<Integer> visitor = new Visitor<Integer>() {
       @Override
       public Integer visit(B bObject) {
           // TODO do something with bObject
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public Integer visit(C cObject) {
           // TODO do something with cObject
           return null;
       }
   };
   ```

   and just call accept:

   ```
   A objA = repo.findById(id);
   Integer result = objA.accept(visitor);
   ```

Comment: Visitor is a solution to the small example given. If subclasses are added to `A` in the future (`D`, `E`, `F`, `G`) then Visitor becomes a maintenance problem, so we lose extensibility through that patttern. Moving the `process()` method into `A` and overriding it in subclasses is far simpler and does not require passing `this`.

Comment: I don't insist on using visitor, I've just described different possibilites. Visitor is useful when class hierarchy is stable and there is a need to add various operations on those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Using overloaded methods in this instance cannot be done without casting the object first since the program will not call the overloaded method if the explicit object type does not match. So it would not call process(B objB) unless the object you were passing is explicitly of class B.

In order to avoid too much hassle, there are a few ways to do it. Depending on what differentiates between B and C, you can instantiate A as that type when pulling the object from the database (this can be done in the RowMapper) and write an if else statement to determine which process to call:

```
        if(a.getClass() == B.class)
        {
            return process((B) a);
        }
        else
        {
            return process((C) a);
        }
```

Or, if you have more subclasses, you can use a switch statement. That is the simplest way I can think of.